# Trouble with redirecting users from https to http using .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, .htaccess

I'm trying to use a .htaccess file to redirect everything from https to normal http (for reasons beyond the scope of this post).

I have tried playing the .htaccess file in the `/httpdocs` directory with the content

`Redirect / http://mysite.com` and `Redirect * mysite.com` (the http:// should be there, but I cannot post it because "new users are limited to posting one link")

but neither of those has worked.

What am I doing wrong?

If it is helpful, I am on CentOS on a normal LAMP stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Where should this be placed? In /httpsdocs directory or the root directory of the site or what? I have it in the /httpsdocs and it doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: My bad, just edited it. It should go in your root directory of your site. Try the updated code.

Comment: Also, make sure you don't have `AllowOverride None` specified in your VHost.